# maven build issue - exclude folders from build

Tags: maven

I am running mvn clean install. Trying to excluded a folder from being included in the maven build. Entry in maven config:

```
<configuration>              
   <excludes>
        <exclude>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/test</exclude>
   </excludes>
</configuration>
```

Getting this exception -
*Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.2.RELEASE:repackage for parameter exclude: Cannot find default setter in class org.springframework.boot.maven.Exclude*

How to resolve this? Any suggestions.

Comment: Can you post the whole POM?

Answer (score 1):

If someone came here, solution is put `artifactId` and `groupId` as in [example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging.examples.exclude-dependency).

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    <configuration>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>
          <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
          <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
        </exclude>
      </excludes>
    </configuration>
    ...
  </plugin>
```

Comment: if i add your exclude recomendation, i keep getting that mistake, but when i write the groupId directly after exclude tag, the maven skip it  ... 
but throws another error [image] (http://prntscr.com/ub19kq)

Comment: In your screenshot groupid and artifactid are commented, this is cause of error. If you want to exclude you should uncomment that

Comment: thanks for answering, but look, i just missed that ss:

- Only groupId without further tags = skip but error -> http://prntscr.com/ub31qf
- Both tags uncommented = no skip and failure because of undesired package execution execution -> http://prntscr.com/ub35to

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming form [spring-boot-maven-plugin](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html). First exclude that plugin and try again.